# socket ECONNRESET error sails.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am getting a message when i lift sails as mentioned below:

```
  info: socket error Error: read ECONNRESET
        at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

And , my process is not executed as well.

In my process , i am using **socket.post method** to process the data.

Is this socket error stopping my process execution?

What is the cause of this error ? How can i solve this ?

Please help me.

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose your problem.  What do you mean by "my process is not executed?".  Is Sails not lifting?  Do you have old browser tabs/windows open when you lift Sails that may be trying to reconnect sockets?

Comment: I deployed my project in web server with port 80. When i do sails lift , sails lifted but my socket.post code not executing. I am getting an info message as below. info: socket error Error: read ECONNRESET
        at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)

Comment: Better, but still not clear enough.  "In my process I am using socket.post method to process the data"--what data?  Are you saying you're doing a `socket.post` from the Sails server to another server?  How about showing some code?  Generally `ECONNRESET` means you're trying to communicate with an external server and it hung up on you, making the problem something on their end.

Comment: in my project /application , iam using knockout.js . in that i have wriiten socket.post () to send frontend data to sailsjs controller as below. socket.post("/controllername/actionname" , data , callback function) ..this socket.post is not executing